# Why are attributes in different objects connected to each other when a default argument is given?

Tags: python, class, object, arguments, default

I am implementing a basic node object in python. Basically, I implemented a node class with the attribute **f_pointers** and set it to the default value **[]**. When ever I try to change **f_pointers** of (lets say) **node_a**, I will end up changing **f_pointers** of **node_b**, which are programmed to be completely unrelated.

I have already solved the problem by instead changing the default value to None and setting up the forward_pointers in __init__. However, I would still like to know how to avoid this problem in the future and possibly learn something new about Python.

For the sake of simplicity, I removed some unnecessary parts of the code.

```py
class Node:
     def __init__(self, f_pointers = []):
          self.f_pointers = f_pointers
     def get_pointers(self):
          return self.f_pointers
     def add_pointers(self, new_pointer):
          self.f_pointers.append(new_pointer)
```

```py
a = Node()
b = Node()
print(a.get_pointers, b.get_pointers)

>>> [] []

a.add_pointers("a")
print(a.get_pointers, b.get_pointers)

>> ["a"] ["a"]

a.add_pointers("b")
print(a.get_pointers, b.get_pointers)

>> ["a","b"] ["a","b"]
```

As can be seen, a and b are completely unrelated objects (other than the fact that they are of the same type Node) but will affect each other. Why does this happen?

Comment: Your problem is called "mutable default arguments". Read about it in the question I linked to as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are referencing to the same list (the one instantiated in the `__init__` default params list definition like `__init__(self, f_pointers=[])`. What happens is that when you say in the `__init__` method code block that `self.f_points = f_pointers` you are basically **referencing the same list every time you instantiate** a new `Node` object.

The reasons are explained further [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)

What you do want to do instead is instantiate a new list for every init like:

```
def __init__(self, f_pointers=None):
    self.f_pointers = []
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this.

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, f_pointers=None):
        if f_pointers:
            self.f_pointers = f_pointers
        else:
            self.f_pointers = []
    def get_pointers(self):
        return self.f_pointers
    def add_pointers(self, new_pointer):
        self.f_pointers.append(new_pointer)

a = Node()
b = Node()

print(a.get_pointers(), b.get_pointers())

a.add_pointers("a")
print(a.get_pointers(), b.get_pointers())
```

You get this kind of behavior because in your case `a.f_pointers` and `b.f_pointers` is the same list, which was generated, when you described your class Node.
So `a.f_pointers is b.f_pointers == True` in your case